# retrieving latitude and longitude from database(db2) and show in map in IBM worklight

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

I have saved latitude and longitude in database(db2).I want to use them to show their location in map.I am working with IBM Worklight and as database I am using DB2.
My problem is I can retrieve value from database,store it in a variable but could not be able to pass the value in the function of map where it can be used as latitude and longitude.

> Any positive help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

My approach:

CODE:

```
    var mylat;
    var mylon;
    var clat;
    var clon;


    function maplo() {

    //database value,I have stored them in a text input type

         clat=$("#lati").val(); 
         clon=$("#long").val();


    }


    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        mylat=position.coords.latitude;
        mylon=position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function success(position) {
        //reload();
        maplo();
        showPosition(position); 



        var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
          mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
          mapcanvas.style.height = '460px';
          mapcanvas.style.width = '320px';

          document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);


            var flat=clat;
            var flon=clon;
            alert("custom latitude is : "+flat);

          var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          var coords1 = new google.maps.LatLng(flat, flon);
          var options = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: coords,
              map: map,
              title:"You are here!"
          });

          var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: coords1,
              map: map,
              title: 'Your car location',
              icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
          });

        }



        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
        } else {
          error('Geo Location is not supported');
        }


function searchcarl()
{

var a=$("#searchcar").val();
var invocationData={
        adapter:'park',
            procedure :'procedure4',
            parameters:[a]
};
var options={
    onSuccess:success6,
    onFailure:fail6

};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}




function success6(result){
    if((result.invocationResult.resultSet.length)>0)
    {
        alert("location fetching!");
        var I=result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].LAT;
        var J=result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].LON;


        $("#lati").val(I);
        $("#long").val(J);
    }

    else{
        alert("Incorrect Username or Password!");
        window.location.assign("#log");
    }
}
function fail6()
{
    alert("fail6");
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you've actually really retrieved the value and that the value is what you are expecting (print it in an alert...). Preview your application via the Worklight Console in Chrome with the DevTools' console open. Do you see any errors?

Comment: I you asking me that where I have retrieved the desired value from database or not,then the answer is yes.but my problem is I have the retrieved value from database stored in 2 variables(for latitude and longitude) but cant pass them into the success function properly.

Comment: You need to explain your code. What are those 2 variables? clan/long or mylan/lon? what is clon? you're getting it from the HTML, not the database.

Comment: function success6(result){
 if((result.invocationResult.resultSet.length)>0)
 {
  alert("location fetching!");
  var I=result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].LAT;
  var J=result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].LON;
  
  
  $("#lati").val(I);
  $("#long").val(J);
 }
 
 else{
  alert("Incorrect Username or Password!");
  window.location.assign("#log");
 }
}
this is function where I retrieved latitude and longitude from database and put them in a text area whose id is lati and long.In this page I picked up values from those text fields and stored them in the global variable clat and clon.

Comment: If you fetch them from the database, why do you need to place them in the HTML and again into a variable in the JS? why not put them directly in the values in the JS from the invocation result?

Comment: You are right.anyway I have submitted the code of database fetching also.You can take a look and suggest me what I should do.The necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will update the code as follows:

```
// create a map global variable 
var map;

function initMap(position) {

  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
    mapcanvas.style.height = '460px';
    mapcanvas.style.width = '320px';

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(mapcanvas);

    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var options = {
        zoom : 16,
        center : coords,
        mapTypeControl : false,
        navigationControlOptions : {
            style : google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : coords,
        map : map,
        title : "You are here!"
    });
}

// adds a marker to the map
function addCarLocationMarker(lat, lng) {

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : cords,
        map : map,
        title : 'Your car location',
        icon : 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
    });
}


if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // once you know the user location, init the map
    initMap(position);
  });

} else {
    alert('Geo Location is not supported');
}



function searchcarl() {

    var a = $("#searchcar").val();
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'park',
        procedure : 'procedure4',
        parameters : [ a ]
    };
    var options = {
        onSuccess : adapterSuccess,
        onFailure : adapterFailed

    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}

function adapterSuccess(result) {
    if ((result.invocationResult.resultSet.length) > 0) {
        alert("location fetching!");
        var I = result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].LAT;
        var J = result.invocationResult.resultSet[0].LON;

    // add the marker directly to the map
    addCarLocationMarker(I, J);
    }

    else {
        alert("Incorrect Username or Password!");
        window.location.assign("#log");
    }
}

function adapterFailed() {
    alert("adapter invocation failed");
}
```

Like Idan mentioned, it's not a good idea to store the coordinates in text boxes to then use the text boxes as the source of the coordinates.

You should add the marker directly after you received the coordinates from the adapter. In this case I created a separate function `initMap` to initialize the map and center it on the current user's location. It is a good idea to make your functions smaller to perform one single task.

I removed some function that I thought you didn't need or were duplicating functionality namely `maplo`, `getLocation` and `showPosition`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code.But after writing this code the map is coming in front of the application,actually its overlapping the default page of my app.what should I do?

Comment: Thanks a lot Yoel Nunez,problem has been solved.But I need another help.How can I show a route between these 2 points

Comment: @TuhinSubhra if your initial concern is solved/answered please mark the question as answered. For directions/routing you can follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple if you have questions while doing that open another question and tag it with `gogole-maps`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am new here.So I didn't know.I have marked it as solved.